# Issue in reading a excel file from SFTP server using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am new in Spring integration so it might be silly for experts.

I want to read a excel file which is on a SFTP server every morning (for now i set to read every minute as below). I have written all code which recive a inputstream of excel and using POI traverse it.

if i give file manualy like uploaded from JSP then no issue, everything works fine.

But when i enable spring integration using below code then it give me error.

I found that "DefaultSftpSessionFactory" has inner dependency on "jsch-0.1.51.jar" and that is also getting bundle as part of my artifcact.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/session/DefaultSftpSessionFactory.html

I am using spring 4.0.9.

**FYI, Control is not coming till my "processFTPFile" method.**

```
    <bean id="ultiProSftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="serverhost" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />

    </bean>

    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundChannelAdapter" session-factory="ultiProSftpSessionFactory" channel="fileAvailableChannel" 
            filename-pattern="* Consolidated Report.xlsx"
            remote-directory="/folder1/folder2"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="."
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            auto-startup="true">
            <int:poller cron="0 0/1 * * * *">
            </int:poller>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator id="serviceUpdateTrackingItem" method="processFTPFile" ref="cAPunchDataAdapter" input-channel="fileAvailableChannel" />

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="fileAvailableChannel"/>
```

Code that i want to execute on each file

```
    @Component("cAPunchDataAdapter")
    public class CAPunchDataAdapter {


        public void processFTPFile(FTPFile file) {

            //Code goes here to get inputstream of file.


        }

    }
```

Below is error logs.

```
    [3/4/19 18:20:00:731 EST] 00002560 SystemErr     R [ERROR] LoggingHandler - -org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:209)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:191)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:321)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry incompatible with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter.getFilename(FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter.java:29)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractSimplePatternFileListFilter.accept(AbstractSimplePatternFileListFilter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.filterFiles(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:173)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:312)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: Hey @Parivesh. Could you please provide me the code to read .xls from sftp server and then traversing it using poi.

Comment: @SrijaMyaka Its been long time, and I dont have that code any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSch is for **sftp**, you are using **ftp**.

You need

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundChannelAdapter" session-factory="ultiProSftpSessionFactory" channel="fileAvailableCh
```

(`int-sftp:`, not `int-ftp:`)

Answer (score -1):

Found the fix, I was not expected in that way.

replaced

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter
```

with

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
```

Spring should have implemented better error message :) .

Comment: You should use maven or gradle to manage dependencies. Then you won't encounter problems like this. There is nothing Spring can do to help.if you mess up the dependencies.

Comment: This is the answer as given by @GaryRussell - please accept his answer

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Gary Russel's answer came at 2019-03-05 01:40:13Z while this answer came at 2019-03-05 01:40:17Z (4 seconds later).

Comment: Whatever.. thank to all, so much interest and investing time to find out who is the winner...